# List<Model> is not a realm model type

Tags: flutter, dart, realm

I'm new to Realm, and I want to use it [with Flutter (Dart)](https://github.com/realm/realm-dart), but I have a problem when generating *g file* with this command

```
flutter pub run realm generate
```

This is the error in terminal:

```
➜  app-android git:(develop) ✗ flutter pub run realm generate
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 763ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 132ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 1.3s

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 28ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 58ms

[SEVERE] realm:realm_generator on lib/Models/FavoritesModel/favorites_model.dart (cached):

Not a realm type

in: package:test_app/Models/FavoritesModel/favorites_model.dart:11:14
╷
6   │ @RealmModel()
7   │ class _FavoritesModel {
    │       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ in realm model for 'FavoritesModel'
... │
11  │   late final List<AudiosArticleModel> data;
    │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ List<AudiosArticleModel> is not a realm model type
    ╵
Remove the invalid field or add an @Ignored annotation on 'data'.

[SEVERE] Failed after 110ms
```

Here is my **favorites_model.dart** file:

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
import '../AudiosArticleModel/audios_article_model.dart';
part 'favorites_model.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _FavoritesModel {

  late String title;
  late String author;
  late final List<AudiosArticleModel> data;
}
```

Does someone know what's the problem ? I already generated successfully the AudiosArticle Model with the same command.

**audios_article_model.dart**

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
part 'audios_article_model.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _AudiosArticleModel {
  late String link;
  late String title;
  late String author;
  late String hour;
  late String minute;
  late String second;
}
```

**audios_article_model.g.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'audios_article_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RealmObjectGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class AudiosArticleModel extends _AudiosArticleModel with RealmObject {
  AudiosArticleModel(
    String link,
    String title,
    String author,
    String hour,
    String minute,
    String second,
  ) {
    this.link = link;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }

  AudiosArticleModel._();

  @override
  String get link => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'link') as String;
  @override
  set link(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'link', value);

  @override
  String get title => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'title') as String;
  @override
  set title(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'title', value);

  @override
  String get author => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'author') as String;
  @override
  set author(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'author', value);

  @override
  String get hour => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'hour') as String;
  @override
  set hour(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'hour', value);

  @override
  String get minute => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'minute') as String;
  @override
  set minute(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'minute', value);

  @override
  String get second => RealmObject.get<String>(this, 'second') as String;
  @override
  set second(String value) => RealmObject.set(this, 'second', value);

  static SchemaObject get schema => _schema ??= _initSchema();
  static SchemaObject? _schema;
  static SchemaObject _initSchema() {
   RealmObject.registerFactory(AudiosArticleModel._);
   return const SchemaObject(AudiosArticleModel, [
    SchemaProperty('link', RealmPropertyType.string),
    SchemaProperty('title', RealmPropertyType.string),
    SchemaProperty('author', RealmPropertyType.string),
    SchemaProperty('hour', RealmPropertyType.string),
    SchemaProperty('minute', RealmPropertyType.string),
    SchemaProperty('second', RealmPropertyType.string),
     ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems the compiler is not seeing the - *AudiosArticleModel* - at all. Possibly not being included correctly. Is there a decrepacy in the naming of the includes parts? `part 'audios_article_model.g.dart'` and `part of 'audios_article_model.dart'`? All of the Realm objects need to be visible and included e.g. if the .g file is not included, it won't see the base Realm Class.

Comment: @Jay what do you mean "decrepacy" ?

Comment: That was a typo: discrepancy -> "a lack of similarity". Those two .dart parts have different names.

Comment: @Jay I checked, and I deleted those files and created new ones. Same problem. I guess this is an alpha release, so maybe it's from the library?

Comment: Try something, modify the `favorites_model.dart` file and add another line `import '../AudiosArticleModel/audios_article_model.g.dart;` just to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem: the model class was private because of **_** prefix.

The solution is to use **$** prefix instead to make it public for all project.

**audios_article_model.dart**

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
part 'audios_article_model.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class $AudiosArticleModel {
  late String link;
  late String title;
  late String author;
  late String hour;
  late String minute;
  late String second;
}
```

Of course you need to generate g file.